# Get all results from Google Place API

Tags: php, curl, google-places-api

I am using PHP curl to get Google Place API result. I am using below code for this :

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
       CURLOPT_URL => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=CITY&type=atm&next_page_token=40&key=KEY'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

From above request i got only 20 results but i want all result. To get all result i used "next_page_token" parameter like below :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=CITY&type=atm&next_page_token=20&key=KEY
```

Above URL return only next 20 record but not all. So finally i have only 40 record but still i am not able to get all record.

Can anyone please help me out what should i do with url.

Comment: I guess you have to use the API to get 20 and 20 records at a time. This is pretty common for APIs to avoid returning a huge payload. What does the API documentation tell you?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Comment: Read the first line in the docs and you should be good. Try this first next time.

Comment: I read the documentation and i was able to do it by using "pagetoken" but it returns only 60 records. Is there any way i can get all results?